# How to get the table schema dynamically using Subsonic 3.0?

Tags: schema, subsonic, subsonic3

I have a page and it lists bunch of tables in a drop down list. I need to load up a list of columns in the database dynamically. In Subsonic 2.0 it could have been done by Subsonic.Schema.BuildTableSchema but not sure how to do it in 3.0. I tried using the code below but does not work ..

```
SubSonic.Schema.DatabaseTable D = new SubSonic.Schema.DatabaseTable("Users",    
        SubSonic.DataProviders.ProviderFactory.GetProvider("ApplicationConnectionString"));

    foreach (SubSonic.Schema.IColumn Column in D.Columns)
    {
      ListItem Item = new ListItem();

      if ((Column.Name ?? "").IndexOf("Email") != -1)
      {
        Item.Selected = true;
      }

      ddlEmailColumn.Items.Add(Item);
      ddlEmailColumn.SelectedValue = Column.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think anyone is going to reply to this, so I did it the hard way using the following following sql queries:

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns                                                                                             WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Name'

SELECT [name]                                                                                        FROM syscolumns                                                                                         WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [id]                                                                                         FROM sysobjects                                                                         WHERE [name] = 'Table_Name')                                                                               AND colid IN (SELECT SIK.colid                                                                                         FROM sysindexkeys SIK                                                                                         JOIN sysobjects SO ON SIK.[id] = SO.[id]                                                                                          WHERE SIK.indid = 1                                                                                        AND SO.[name] = 'Table_Name')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the syntax differences in SubSonic, but I know that in 2.2 I am able to do:

```
Array arr = MyTable.Schema.Columns.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In SubSonic 3.0 you shouldn't need to do that. The schema is captured at compile time by the T4 macros, and is available at runtime. You'll find it in the code generated from Structs.tt.

At a rough approximation the code is

```
foreach (var column in UsersTable.Columns) {
    // do stuff with column
}
```